# Playing Civ V with Steam on different PC

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

My friend and I want to play Civ V together using LAN. His laptop isn't te newest one and has some performance issues so we thought that he could play on mine using his Steam account since I have two computers anyway.

Would it be a problem since we haven't purchased the same DLCs? Would Steam use the version of Civilisation that I have installed on my PC or what he has bought and linked to his account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend will be able to use the Civ V files installed on your second PC but will only be able to access DLCs and expansions that he owns. If he does not have Gods & Kings or Brave New World, he will not be able to play with them.

All players in a multiplayer game need to have all the DLCs that are in use. This means you will have to play vanilla unless you both own G&K and BNW.